# How to handle dynamic request body without creating request class?

Tags: java, api, rest, post, request

I have an api endpoint with request body like this.

```
{
   "employeeId" : "1234",
   "empName" : "John"
}
```

The fields are dynamic. So instead of creating a request class I am passing request body as HashMap<String, String> as below.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getEmployees(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> queryParams){

}
```

Now my requirement is to add something like this in the request body along with other dynamic fields.

```
{
  "empAwardsReceived" : ["On the spot award", "Best employee award"]
}
```

How can we handle this?
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed RequestBody from HashMap<String, String> to HashMap<String, Object> and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `@RequestBody String queryParams` instead of `@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> queryParams`.

Then you could try to look at eg. the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library, which would help you to parse JSON as you want.

You probably could use code like presented below.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(queryParams);
```

Then you could manipulate on JsonNode by using methods mentioned eg. in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model#manipulating).

So adding a new JSON node should not be a problem.